# Boot Gateway DX4860-UR308 to USB Live

Tags: installation, live-usb, secure-boot

I have a new DX4860-UR308  BIOS version P11-A0. The Secure Boot is disabled and the 1st Boot Device is set to Removable Device and the 2nd is set to CD. I have a Live USB and Live CD in each, respectively, but still machine boots to Windows.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have another computer to validate the live media? Since this is a new pc perhaps there's a hardware malfunction

Answer (score 0):

Issue turned out that pc "sees" usb device as a hard drive, so that's where to prioritize boot order. Strange, I think.

Comment: Are you the original poster of the question? This does not seem like an answer.